# .net core CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance doesnt add any encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to use windows-1252 encoding in my .netcore 2.0 app. and as per the documentation I need to add [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) package and register it to be able to use this encoding. but it does not work and when I debugged it I see that the provider has 0 encodings

```
   EncodingProvider provider = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(provider);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to get the Encoding object : `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, your screenshot refer to a cache of already accessed encoding. So by default the cache is empty.

To see it yourself use this snippet :

```
// add a spy in visual studio with this :
// ((System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider)CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)._encodings

Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
// here the spy should have as value of "Count = 0"

var xx = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
// now the value is "Count = 1"
```

This encoding instance will not support all standard properties. Some of them will throw `NotSupportedException`.

[image: Available properties]

Comment: I still get an error `xx.BodyName' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'` `No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method`

Comment: Can you try to create a program with only these two line?

Comment: Can your share a simple repro ? A .cs file and a .csproj . To see what's different.

Comment: Ok, I see. The issue is that the Encoding provided doesn't support all properties of native Encoding. You can use `CodePage`; `EncodingName` or `WebName` instead of `BodyName`

Comment: but the string what I am trying to encode is not encoding properly

Comment: Can you add this to the repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180073/discussion-between-kalten-and-joe-b).